# Localhost ASP.NET Core Web API can't connect with Xamarin forms app. "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Network subsystem is down' " error

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I am connecting my Xamarin Forms app with an ASP.NET Core API. My API works fine, get response from localhost server, but when I call this API with Xamarin app, then I get this error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Network subsystem is down'

My API url is `https://localhost:57347/`;

My API call function is shown here:

```
public static async Task<bool> Login(string email, string password)
{
    var login = new Login()
                {
                    Email = email,
                    Password = password
                };

    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(ApiUrl + "api/Logins/login", content);

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        return false;

    var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonResult);
       
    return true;
}
```

I use

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
```

instead of `HttpClient` because of this error:

> Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.'

Still I can't connect to the API from Xamarin Forms.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: is there nobody to answer?

Comment: since there is no solution given. i search for it and get suggestion to use  url as 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost. so my current url  is  http://10.0.2.2:57347/;  
but getting
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{} error

Comment: The StatusCode 400 means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules. So you can recheck if the request data is right.